# Ionic + Angular ng-click not bind function from dynamic html element

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-click

I have an ion-list and I create each ion-item from a select statment. The ion-item tag has a *ng-click* event that call a modal window but it never call the *show()* method from controller. For test I put a static ion-item without DOM modification and it works well.

This is the code:

Modal controller

```
function uib_w_27_modal_controller($scope, $ionicModal) {
  $scope.modal = $ionicModal.fromTemplate($(".uib_w_27").html(), {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  });
  $scope.show = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };
  $scope.close = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
  //Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
  $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.modal.remove();
  });
  // Execute action on hide modal
  $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function() {
    // Execute action
  });
  // Execute action on remove modal
  $scope.$on('modal.removed', function() {
    // Execute action
  });
};
```

Dynamic element

```
function getFarmaciasSelect(tx, result){
    var elem = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
        var row = result.rows.item(i);
        elem += '<ion-item class="item widget uib_w_24 d-margins item-avatar item-icon-right" data-uib="ionic/list_item_avatar" data-ver="0">' +
                            '<img src="images/Strabburg.jpg">' +
                            '<h2>' + row['nombre'] + '</h2>' +
                            '<p>' + row['calle'] + ' ' + row['altura'] + '</p>' +
                            '<a href="tel:' + row['fijo'] + '"style="text-decoration:none;color:#4CAF50" >' + row['fijo'] + '</a>' +
                            '<i class="icon ion-plus-circled ion" uib-icon-position="right" ng-controller="uib_w_27_modal_controller" ng-click="show()" data-email="email@email.com"></i>' +
                 '</ion-item>';
            console.log(elem); 
    }
    $('#farmacias-list').html(elem);
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Could you post a fiddle? And a second thing: Why aren't you doing the dynamic-element-part with a ng-repeat in your html?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to keep generating in your code then you need **compile your content before add** to '#farmacias-list'

```
$('#farmacias-list').html($compile(elem)($scope));
```

but even it work, I will recommend you to **use collection-repeat to generate content in angular context**.